# Always display top of Silverlight page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am developing a Silverlight navigation application which has 3 parts:

- one upper part where the company logo is shown along with a menu (fixed height)
- the middle part holds the navigation frame (variable height)
- the bottom part has some copyright information and a sound on/off button(fixed height)

The middle part stretches as much as needed to display the whole content but then it also sets the view to the middle of the page. I would like to always have the top of the page (the menu) displayed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you are describing is essentially a "Silverlight Navigation Application".  If you create a project of this type the template will give you most of what you described at the outset.

Have created this new project I recommend the following changes.  Modify the main page to look like this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootGridStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="NavigationGrid" Style="{StaticResource NavigationGridStyle}">
         <!-- Cut for brevity -->
    </Grid>

    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Style="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
         <!-- Cut for brevity -->
    </Border>

    <Border x:Name="FooterBorder" Style="{StaticResource FooterBorderStyle}" Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Copyright info here" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Modify the "NavigationGridStyle" and "ContentBorderStyle" and also add the "FooterBorderStyle" in the /Assets/styles.xaml like this:-

```
  <Style x:Key="ContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.045" StartPoint="0.5,0">
          <GradientStop Color="#6FCCCCCC"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#00CCCCCC" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,3,0,0"/>
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="NavigationGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NavigationBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="FooterBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
      <!-- Whatever styling if any you want here -->
  </Style>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear... I want the menu to be displayed after every navigation... At the momment i always have the screen center at the middle of the navigation page... so if there is a longer message message the user will see the middle of the page and not the top (beggining) of the page... put it another way... i want the scrollbar to be always on it's highest position...

Comment: @Ivan: I agree you aren't making yourself clear at all.  Why would you have such a menu included in scrollable region at all?  why not place it above the content that is to be scrolled?   "always have the screen center at the middle of the navigation page", it would take some effort to create that result rather than things starting from the beginning.  Perhaps you should edit your quesiton with some real example because its difficult to see how you managing to have this difficulty in the first place.

Comment: i will qoute myself : "•one upper part where the company logo is shown along with a menu (fixed height)"... i have the menu on top it's in the navigationGrid... and i want it to always be visible... i have managed it by setting `scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);` and it works fine for all but one case.. i am now looking for the problem... all i want is to always after a navigation have the top of the page displayed so that the menu along with the title of the current page is visible

Comment: @Ivan:  I think I shall throw in the towel at this point.  I believe what I have already posted delivers the requirement that I'm seeing. Perhaps you need to rollback some of your work or just play with the example I've given so that you grasp how it works.

Comment: @Anthony: Could you just explain how setting a background color will force the application to display the top of a page?

Comment: @Ivan: It doesn't as I'm sure you well know.  I understand you are frustrated however I have tried to help you but clearly we are not communicating well.  So far the described problem is achieved by the mechanism I've described. If this doesn't work for then I'm afraid no amount of my re-reading what you have written is going to help.  Your only chance is to include more detail in your question.  Its worth remembering that some words like "Page" can mean different things (HTML Page or Silverlight Page are different) so try to be extra precise in your terminology.